# Android custom view obtain multiple attributes

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view in Android. In it's constructor I am obtaining some of the attributes that are set in the XML layout file. The code is like this:

```
public LabeledEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray styledAttrs = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.id, android.R.attr.digits, android.R.attr.padding, android.R.attr.inputType }, 0, 0);
    try {
        int id = styledAttrs.getResourceId(styledAttrs.getIndex(0), -1);
        String digits = styledAttrs.getString(styledAttrs.getIndex(1));
        float padding = styledAttrs.getDimension(styledAttrs.getIndex(2), 0.1f);
        int inputType = styledAttrs.getInt(styledAttrs.getIndex(3), -1);
    } finally {
        styledAttrs.recycle();
    }
}
```

The problem is that obtainStyledAttributes does not obtain all the attributes, even though they exist in the attribute set. What's even stranger, is that if I change the ordering of the ids in the int array I get different results. For example, if I use the following ordering

```
new int[] { android.R.attr.id, android.R.attr.digits, android.R.attr.padding, android.R.attr.inputType }
```

I get back 3 attributes, but if I use the following ordering

```
new int[] {android.R.attr.digits, android.R.attr.padding, android.R.attr.inputType, android.R.attr.id }
```

I get back 2. I'm including 2 screenshots of the watches window of these 2 cases. The breakpoint is set just after the try statement.

[image: 1st ordering]

[image: 2nd ordering]

In any case if I obtain the attributes one at a time, it works for all of them. How does obtainStyledAttributes works? Also I'm not sure if I should use the styledAttrs.getIndex(i) function or not, but that is a problem after the current one is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not documented, `obtainStyledAttributes` expects a sorted array, and its code is optimized with that assumption.

So you need to provide your `styledAttrs` array with the elements sorted in ascending order according to their id values.

There are several ways you can determine the correct order:

- based on their relative position in the resources
- by checking their relative values and changing the array to match
- or by sorting the array elements programmatically

If you choose to sort the array programmatically at run time, make sure you use the appropriate (sorted) index when calling `getString()` etc.

Another common workaround is to only get a single value with `obtainStyledAttributes` at a time. (An array with one element is already sorted.)

> Also I'm not sure if I should use the styledAttrs.getIndex(i) function or not

I believe that's only necessary if you're looping through the `TypedArray` and its possible some of the elements may not have values; it basically "hides" the null elements for you as though it were a sparse array. In general I don't think it's necessary unless you're accessing styled resources in certain ways, for example when implementing a custom view.

Most of the time I use custom theme attributes that aren't related to a view at all, and in those cases I've always found `TypedArray.getIndex()` to be redundant.